# Why do this recursive function fails with stack overflow? How can I improve it?

Tags: string, scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I am thinking of writing a recursive function in scala that concatenate the string for n times.
My code is below:

```
def repeat(s: String, n: Int): String = {
   if(n==1) s
   else 
     s+repeat(s,n-1)
}
```

Is it possible that I did not use "+" properly? But the "+" is indeed a sign of concatenation, as I was originally trying

```
def repeat(s: String, n: Int): String = {
if(n==1) s
else 
  repeat(s+s,n-1)
 }
```

That repeats my string 2^n times

Comment: a recursive function in scala that concatenate the string for n times.`def repeat(s: String, n: Int):`

Comment: Your code works for me (as long as n >= 1). Does it not work for you? Please explain.

Comment: `s+repeat(s,n-1)` does not work. The program aborts on eclipse.

Comment: Like I said, if you copy and paste the code you put for the first example (which includes `s+repeat(s,n-1)`), it works fine. Could you show us what code *doesn't* work?

Comment: When you say "the program aborts", do you mean you get an error? What error? Is it a compile error or a runtime error? And what program is this? Just a simple test of that function, or something more complicated?

Comment: *** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.StackOverflowError:
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.<init>(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.<init>(Seq.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractSeq.<init>(Seq.scala:47)
  at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.scala:28)
  at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.scala:46)
  at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.scala:51)
  at Lab1$.repeat(Lab1.scala:93)
  at Lab1$.repeat(Lab1.scala:93)
  at Lab1$.repeat(Lab1.scala:93)
  at Lab1$.repeat(Lab1.scala:93)

Comment: Alright, so your code overflows the stack when you use a large number for `n`. That means it's not tail recursive, so look at flavian's answer and/or read up on tail recursion.

Comment: Think I got it by changing the base case to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@annotation.tailrec
final def repeat(s: String, n: Int, ss: String = ""): String = {
    if (n == 0) ss else repeat(s, n - 1, ss + s)
}
repeat("test", 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first version is NOT tail recursive.

It has to call itself and *then* prepends s.  For tail recursion the very last expression *must* be the self-call.  This means it'll blow the stack for large values of `n`

The second version *is* tail recursive.

Put `@annotation.tailrec` before both definitions, and the compiler will throw an error where it can't perform tail-call optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach that bypasses recursion,

```
def repeat(s: String, n: Int) = s * n
```

Hence,

```
scala> repeat("mystring",3)
res0: String = mystringmystringmystring
```

This function may be rewritten into a recursive form for instance as follows,

```
def re(s: String, n: Int): String  = n match {
  case m if (m <= 0) => ""
  case 1 => s
  case m => s + re(s,n-1)
}
```

Note the uses of `+` and `*` operators on `String`.